# Kohana not work. Not fount classes. Nginx + php-fpm. Digatal Ocean

Tags: php, nginx, kohana, digital-ocean, kohana-3.3

Ubuntu 14.04 + nginx + php-fpm (php 5.5.9)
Kohana 3.3.4

Url: http://188.166.65.233/
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'HTTP_Exception' not found

Not finding the model classes, controllers ... nothing
The error is caused by the fact that Kohana does not see the Controller_Sites, although it is in the folder. On the site of the local machine works fine

====
Config:

php.ini is default, but: cgi.fix_pathinfo=1

nginx site-available default:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /var/www/martds.ru;
    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    server_name martds.ru www.martds.ru;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|xml|docx|xlsx)$ {
        root /var/www/martds.ru;
        index index.html index.php;
        access_log off;
        expires 30d;
    }

    location ~* ^/(?:modules|system)\b.* {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php$1 permanent;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you have error with php autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed was in `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`

DigitalOcean has `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` by default in php.ini, set it back to `1` and everything worked.

Comment: Note that this may be unsafe, user may upload a specially formatted image file that passes validation, but also contains a php payload that may be executed like `/uploads/avatars/exploit.gif/makeitlooklike.php`, see http://habrahabr.ru/post/100961/